# What is the volume of a suspended cauldron?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, equipment, 3d-space

DMG p. 255 provides the stats for siege equipment, and lists [suspended cauldrons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/running-the-game#CauldronSuspended) among them:

> A cauldron is an iron pot suspended so that it can be tipped easily, spilling its contents. Once emptied, a cauldron must be refilled — and its contents must usually be reheated — before it can be used again. It takes three actions to fill a cauldron and one action to tip it.
>
> Cauldrons can be filled with other liquids, such as acid or green slime, with different effects.
>
> ***Boiling Oil.*** The cauldron pours boiling oil onto a 10-foot-square area directly below it. Any creature in the area must make a DC 15 Dexterity saving throw, taking 10 (3d6) fire damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.

I'm trying to figure out how many flasks of acid (a flask contains 1 pint) I'd need to fill this siege engine. It's mostly a measure of cost, and if that would change the damage. If so, how it might.

Answer (score 7):

### An iron pot holds 1 gallon of liquid

The only information we have on how big the cauldron is, is contained in the wuote you provided

> A cauldron is an ***iron pot*** suspended so that it can be tipped easily, spilling its contents.[...]

The only place in the source materials where an iron pot is described is in Chapter 5 of the *Player's Handbook* (p. 153), in the section for [container capacity](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#ContainerCapacity), which lists:

> [...]
>
> Pot, Iron: 1 gallon liquid
>
> [...]

Since 1 gallon equals 8 pints, that means that an Iron Pot would hold 8 flasks' worth of acid.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94682/discussion-on-answer-by-illustro-what-is-the-volume-of-a-suspended-cauldron).